# Joining multiple queries to tables with different amounts of columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have 3 tables named `hosts`, `events` and `series`.

`hosts` contains 4 columns: id, name, website, region

`events` contains 3 columns: id, host, name

`series` contains 9 columns: id, date, bestof, host, event, teamA, teamB, comment

I have a search box that at the moment, searches the database using the teamA and teamB columns. It works, but I'd like to open up the criteria by allowing the user to put in the host name and event name.

Say `series` has a row containing teamA and teamB fields called "goodTeam" and "bestTeam", `hosts` has two rows with names "FIFA" and "NFL", and `events` has two rows with names "Premier League" and "Super Bowl".

As of now, if I search "goodTeam", it will give all matches for that team in both events "Premier League" as well as "NFL". I'd like to be able to search "goodTeam nfl", and it will only return results from goodTeam matches in the NFL, or to refine it even more, I search "goodTeam nfl super bowl" and it only returns matches from goodTeam, in the NFL Super Bowl event.

I apologize if it's difficult to understand, I've done my best to explain what I'm trying to do. I've tried UNION ALL with setting the existing columns to NULL, but I think I've done it wrong as it returns everything from the `hosts` table that fits the criteria, not from the `series` table, which is what I need.

```
$sql = "SELECT
    id as host,
    null as date,
    null as id,
    null as bestof,
    null as event,
    null as teamA,
    null as teamB,
    null as comment,
    name,
    region
FROM hosts WHERE name LIKE '%" . $term . "%'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    host,
    date,
    id,
    bestof,
    event,
    teamA,
    teamB,
    comment,
    null as name,
    null as region
FROM series WHERE teamA LIKE '%" . $term . "%' OR teamB LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you're going to need to use JOIN statements. Since it looks like you're only looking for results in the `series` table, you can join across your tables like so:

```
SELECT series.* FROM series
LEFT JOIN events ON series.event=events.id
LEFT JOIN hosts on events.host=hosts.id
```

Now, you're looking to do a multi-keyword search requiring at least one match for each keyword from any of several columns. This is going to need an iteratively generated WHERE query. For a two-keyword example, you'd have:

```
SELECT series.* FROM series
LEFT JOIN events ON series.event=events.id
LEFT JOIN hosts on events.host=hosts.id
WHERE (series.teamA LIKE '%goodTeam%' OR series.teamB LIKE '%goodTeam%' OR events.name LIKE '%goodTeam%' OR hosts.name LIKE '%goodTeam%')
AND (series.teamA LIKE '%nfl%' OR series.teamB LIKE '%nfl%' OR events.name LIKE '%nfl%' OR hosts.name LIKE '%nfl%')
```

This is fine for small databases, but it's not very efficient. If you're going to have any decent number of rows (>50,000) or if you find things slowing down, I recommend using a extra 'keywords' field or similar in the series table instead, rather than making a join every time. Generate the keyword list when the row is added, and then you can just perform any lookups on that field.